# Drag & Drop Upload - Remove object from input

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a drag & drop upload file. Everything works, the only problem is to delete single files from the list. I would like that after clicking on DELETE the file will be removed from the list and it will no longer be marked by the file explorer.

```js
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;

        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.className = "upload-file";
                    div.innerHTML = ['<span>[DELETE]</span> ', escape(theFile.name)].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(div, null);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.space {
  border: 2px solid darkorange;
  width: 300px;
}
.upload-file {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #012345;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
span {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="space">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    <output id="list"></output>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet. After click the file and button are removed. I've used jQuery to solve this.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;

        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.className = "upload-file";
                    div.innerHTML = ['<span>[DELETE]</span> ', escape(theFile.name)].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(div, null);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    $(document).on('click', '.upload-file span', function(){
      $('#files').val("");
      $(this).closest('.upload-file').remove();
    });
```

```css
.space {
  border: 2px solid darkorange;
  width: 300px;
}
.upload-file {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #012345;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
span {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="space">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    <output id="list"></output>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything is okay but there is the same problem as above :(.

Answer (score 0):

You need attach a click event to the span and delete the parent node itself on that particular event

```js
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        
 
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
           
                return function(e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.className = "upload-file";
                    div.innerHTML = ['<span onclick="deleteit(event)" >[DELETE]</span> ', escape(theFile.name)].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(div, null);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }
    
   

    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.space {
  border: 2px solid darkorange;
  width: 300px;
}
.upload-file {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #012345;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
span {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="space">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    <output id="list"></output>
</div>
<script>
   function deleteit(event) {         event.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(event.target.parentNode);
   }
</script>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Everything is fine, but it removes all files from the input, not the specific one. 
My guess is that you have to enter the input table and delete the selected one, however, every time the files are loaded, the input will be reset.